# Embedded Visual C++/Why is my Symbol Undefined?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, embedded, windows-mobile-5.0

I am new to this platform, and I am trying to resolve an issue with existing code that was developed by a contractor many years ago.

In Resource.h, I have something that looks like this, where the last two items I have added.

```
#define IDC_HOSPITAL_NAME_LABEL         1069
#define IDC_REASON_LABEL                1070
#define IDC_HOSPITAL_NAME_EDIT          1071
#define IDC_COMMENTS_EDIT               1072
#define IDC_COMMENTS_LABEL              1073
```

I have compiled and deployed several times, I am using the constants in code and it doesn't complain on compile, however, while it might be unrelated to an issue I am trying to resolve, I do notice that in the IDE, if I right click and "Goto" definition of my new added items, it says "The symbol 'IDC_COMMENTS_LABEL' is undefined."

In fact, it will happen even if I do this at the definition, where as it works as expected with the other non-new definitons.

Comment: This is purely a Visual Studio IDE issue and not directly related to any of the tags.  Maybe the code browser database file has a read-only flag set - this may happen if it was placed under source control.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds to me like its just "one of those things".  You will notice plenty.  Try not to get too wound up by them.   In the end ... if it compiles ... don't worry about it :)

Answer (score 1):

Do you have a newline on the last line?  A missing one may confuse the IDE's symbol parser

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried rebuilding? You might also try quitting VS, deleting the intellisense file (*.ncb), and rebuilding.

Comment: Oh yes, I tried rebuilding, closing the UI. Rebuilding All.  The code compiles, the code executes.  I do have one issue, that I thought might be relative to this but I'm thinking not so much anymore, probably unrelated.

Answer (score 0):

This is because, the symbol is probably not added to the Browse Information file of VC++.

In VC++, under Project->Settings->Browse Info ,enable the radio button "Build Browse Info file". Also clean (build->clean) the temporary files.

Now, exit visual studio IDE, delete the (*.ncb) file.

Relaunch VC6++ & rebuild all. That should do.